# I wanted to create a SQL query to list of all customers who have placed an above average number of orders

Tags: sql, oracle, join

SQL query to list of all customers who have placed an above average number of orders.

Order details are present in NW_orders table and Customer info is present in NW_Customers table.

First, I have calculated the Avg number of orders placed by all customers. Then i want to pull only customer who have placed order greater than the avg number of orders.

My query:

```
SELECT 
    C.customerid, C.companyname, COUNT(O.orderid) AS cnt
FROM 
    NW_customers C
LEFT JOIN 
    NW_orders O ON O.customerID = C.Customerid 
GROUP BY 
    C.customerid 
HAVING 
   cnt > (SELECT COUNT(O.OrderID) / COUNT(DISTINCT(c.customerid)) AS Avg
          FROM NW_orders O
          LEFT JOIN NW_customers C ON O.customerID = C.Customerid)
```

I am getting an error

> ORA-00904: "CNT": invalid identifier

Can anyone please help to rectify the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a common table expression:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT o.customerid, COUNT(o.orderid) AS cnt
    FROM NW_orders o
    GROUP BY o.customerid
)

SELECT t.customerid
FROM cte t
WHERE t.cnt > (SELECT AVG(cnt) FROM cte)
```

If you want to bring in actual customer information, you can add a join to the above query:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM cte t1
INNER JOIN NW_customers t2
    ON t1.customerid = t2.customerid
WHERE t1.cnt > (SELECT AVG(cnt) FROM cte)
```

Comment: Tim, putting aside the non-use of analytical functions, `NW_customers` is not needed at all if you wish to retrieve only the `customerid` since only a customer with orders might have placed an above average number of orders.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic for analytic function.

#### cutomerId

```
select      customerID

from       (select      customerID
                       ,count(*)                as customer_orders
                       ,avg  (count(*)) over () as avg_customer_orders

            from        NW_orders

            group by    customerID
            )

where       customer_orders > avg_customer_orders
;
```

#### Full customer information

```
select      *

from        NW_customers

where       customerID in
            (
                select      customerID

                from       (select      customerID
                                       ,count(*)                as customer_orders
                                       ,avg  (count(*)) over () as avg_customer_orders

                            from        NW_orders

                            group by    customerID
                            )

                where       customer_orders > avg_customer_orders
            )
;
```

#### Full customer information + Orders information

```
select      o.customer_orders
           ,o.avg_customer_orders
           ,c.*

from                    NW_customers    c

            join        (select     customerID
                                   ,count(*)                as customer_orders
                                   ,avg  (count(*)) over () as avg_customer_orders

                        from        NW_orders

                        group by    customerID
                        ) o

            on          o.customerID    =
                        c.customerID


where       o.customer_orders > o.avg_customer_orders
;
```